# Can you plot just points in openpxl? No lines

Tags: python, openpyxl, scatter-plot, graphing

I have this function that plots 2 columns of data however I don't want the points to be connected. Anyone know how? I have attempted changing the style number with no luck.

```
def _disp_plot_user(
wb,
worksheet_name: str,
x_column_number: int,
y_column_number: int,
xtitle: str,
ytitle: str,
):
ws = wb[worksheet_name]
chart = ScatterChart()
chart.style = 11

title = ytitle + " vs " + xtitle
x_column_numb = x_column_number - 1
y_column_numb = y_column_number - 1
list = [x_column_numb, y_column_numb]
x_data = []
y_data = []
data = x_data
for i in list:
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=4):
        item = row[i].value
        data.append(item)

    data = y_data
# lenx = len(x_data)
# leny = len(y_data)

xvalues = Reference(
    ws, min_col=x_column_number, min_row=6, max_col=x_column_number, max_row=4
)
yvalues = Reference(
    ws, min_col=y_column_number, min_row=6, max_col=y_column_number, max_row=4
)
size = Reference(ws, min_col=3, min_row=2, max_row=5)
series = Series(values=yvalues, xvalues=xvalues, zvalues=size, title=title)
chart.series.append(series)
chart.title = title
chart.x_axis.title = xtitle
chart.y_axis.title = ytitle
ws.add_chart(chart, "I3")

return wb
```

Comment: The documentation contains an example: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/line.html

Comment: I have been able to get it to add the triangle markers. However, I cant get it to remove the solid line. Any ideas? @CharlieClark